# Existe botão curtir do facebook para cada produto?

Tags: facebook

Gostaria de colocar em meu site o botão curtir do facebook para cada produto, pois ao clicar no botão o produto com sua foto e características possa aparecer no mural do cliente, o que tenho hoje é o botão que curte a fan page do facebook, não consegui encontrar nenhuma orientação ou dica sobre o assunto.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sim existe, conforme a documentação [**Facebook like button**](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button), existe o atributo `data-href` aonde você pode definir a URL absoluta da página que irá curtir.

### HTML5

```all
<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://example.com/produtos/item-2" 
  data-layout="standard" data-action="like" data-show-faces="true" data-share="true">
</div>
```

### XFBML

```all
<html xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">
...

<fb:like href="http://example.com/produtos/item-1" layout="standard" action="like" 
 show_faces="true" share="true">
</fb:like>

<fb:like href="http://example.com/produtos/item-2" layout="standard" action="like" 
 show_faces="true" share="true">
</fb:like>
```

Para que os botões funcionem, adicione isto logo após abrir o `<body>` (como é sugerido pela documentação):

```all
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>

<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.0";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>

<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://example.com/produtos/item-1" data-layout="standard" 
     data-action="like"  data-show-faces="true" data-share="true">
</div>
```